# How to animate images on mouse hover using Flutter for Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I am a JavaScript developer and I am new to Flutter. I just want to animate a set of images on mouse hover like [this](https://recordit.co/HrHT8kj1Sx) using Flutter for Web. It includes Scaling, Opacity and Grayscale transformations. How to accomplish this in Flutter? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Other than the animation part of your question. The `onHover` argument of the `InkWell` only works if you specify the `onTap` argument first.

```
InkWell(
  child: SomeWidget(),
  onTap: () {
    //You can leave it empty, like that.
  }
  onHover: (isHovering) {
    if (isHovering) {
      //The mouse is hovering.
    } else {
      //The mouse is no longer hovering.
    }
  }
)
```

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/onHover.html), here's the benefit of the `boolean`, which is passed to the `onHover` callback:

> The value passed to the callback is true if a pointer has entered this part of
>   the material and false if a pointer has exited this part of the material.

Comment: Thank you for the info :), I already wondered why Inkwell hovering is not working

Answer (score 8):

This is just a demo to show that you can use `onHover` of `Inkwell` widget to accomplish the task. You will have to come up with the logic to decide how much offset and scale should be used and how to position the widget. In my example I have used a grid view. You can perhaps use a stack to set the currently active widget based on the hover.

Here is the example with a grid view. The live version of this is available in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cd263849836a615820f7a627bd5e249c).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,      
      children: <Widget>[ImageHover(),ImageHover(),ImageHover(),ImageHover(),ImageHover(),ImageHover(),ImageHover(),],
    );
  }
}

class ImageHover extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageHoverState createState() => _ImageHoverState();
}

class _ImageHoverState extends State<ImageHover> {
  double elevation = 4.0;
  double scale = 1.0;
  Offset translate = Offset(0,0);
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return InkWell(      
      onTap: (){},
      onHover: (value){
        print(value);
        if(value){
          setState((){
            elevation = 20.0;     
            scale = 2.0;
            translate = Offset(20,20);
          });
        }else{
          setState((){
            elevation = 4.0; 
            scale = 1.0;
            translate = Offset(0,0);
          });
        }
      },
      child: Transform.translate(
        offset: translate ,        
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: scale,
          child: Material(        
            elevation: elevation,        
            child: Image.network(           
                'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/acm9dCI5_dc/maxresdefault.jpg',              
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I scale this with animation

Answer (score 1):

Just create an extension

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension HoverExtension on Widget {
  Widget get translateOnHover {
    return kIsWeb ? TranslateOnHover(child: this) : ThisContainer(child: this);
  }
}

class ThisContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  ThisContainer({this.child});
  final child;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: child);
  }
}

class TranslateOnHover extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  TranslateOnHover({required this.child});

  @override
  _TranslateOnHoverState createState() => _TranslateOnHoverState();
}

class _TranslateOnHoverState extends State<TranslateOnHover> {
  double scale = 1.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (e) => _mouseEnter(true),
      onExit: (e) => _mouseEnter(false),
      child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: scale),
        builder: (BuildContext context, double value, _) {
          return Transform.scale(scale: value, child: widget.child);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _mouseEnter(bool hover) {
    setState(() {
      if (hover)
        scale = 1.03;
      else
        scale = 1.0;
    });
  }
}
```

And use it anywhere by calling

```dart
yourWidget.translateOnHover
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that there's not a built-in feature already, given that Flutter extended to web also, but luckily there is a package for this: hovering 1.0.4

You just need to install the package running this command `flutter pub add hovering` or adding `hovering: ^1.0.4` to your dependencies. Then you can use `HoverWidget`,`HoverContainer`, `HoverAnimatedContainer`, and some more. It's not perfect, but it's an easy way to do it, specially for not complicated animations.

You can check the official docs of the package for more info: https://pub.dev/packages/hovering